How to retrieve the event log entries from Event viewer using wmi api or window event log API?I have to fetch the below datas and not the properties
System

Provider

[ Name]  MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER01

EventID 25753

[ Qualifiers]  16384
Version 0
Level 4
Task 2
Opcode 0
Keywords 0x80000000000000

TimeCreated

[ SystemTime]  2024-04-25T08:50:12.9568279Z
EventRecordID 17154
Correlation

Execution

[ ProcessID]  0
[ ThreadID]  0
Channel Application
Computer ishacomputer.com

Security

[ UserID]  S-1-5-80-17654264-913341-331818-1608603-13048737

EventData
telemetry_xevents
996400000A0000001C00000068006740037003600300032005C004D005300530051004C00530045005200560045005200300031000000070000006D00610073007400650072000000


How to retrieve the event log entries from Event viewer using wmi api or window event log API?I have tried using WMI API and Window event log APIs but able to fetch only the properties of the logs like recordnumber, sourcename, timewritten, timegenearated, etc., but i like to fetch all the datas liek above in a key value pairs.
